# Printable background image to Excel

Tags: excel, printing

I added background image to Excel using Page Layout->background . But it is not printable. How I can add printable background image to Excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

## Put an Image in the Header

There are quite a few articles online saying that "printable background images" are not possible in Excel.  **But they are, with this workaround.**

Put the image **in the header**, and if it's larger than the size allowed for the header, it will spill into the main part of the page.

Here is a screenshot of a PDF showing a spreadsheet with a very simple EMF (vector) graphic --- a pink, 8"x10" (200x250mm) box.

[image: screenshot of an Excel spreadsheet printed to PDF]

The graphic can even have text in it.  Here is a screenshot of a PDF showing a spreadsheet with a blue, 8"x10" EMF graphic that contains text.

[image]

If you do an EMF/vector image (not a PNG/bitmap image), the quality of any text you put in the background will be excellent:

[image]

Here are the detailed steps.

### To create an EMF graphic

Creating an EMF is easy if you have Inkscape (FLOSS) or PowerPoint:

1. create a new PowerPoint document,
2. draw a box, resize it to 8x10 or similar size,
3. fill it with the desired color and text (if any),
4. right click ⟶ Save as Picture ⟶ select Enhanced Metafile (EMF) format.

> Note: "Save as Picture..." doesn't appear if you are **currently editing text** in a textbox. You need to click the border of the box, to select the box itself and exit 'edit text' mode.

[image: screenshot of Save As Picture dialog box]

### To add the image to your Excel spreadsheet as a background image

1. `Page Layout` ⟶ `Page Setup` ⟶ hit the "arrow button" for the Page Setup Dialog
   [image: Page Setup arrow]
2. Header/Footer Tab ⟶ `"Custom Header..."`
3. Left Section ⟶ press the `Insert Picture...` toolbar button
   [image: screenshot of Insert Picture]
4. Select and add your image.

### Check Your Work

1. Go to View ⟶ `Print Layout` mode to see your picture as a background image.
2. To resize the picture, hit the Page Setup ⟶ `Header/Footer` ⟶ `Format Picture...` toolbar button or just create a new EMF file at the correct size.
3. You can print to PDF or your local printer as desired:

[image: screenshot of entire page]